# python 3.6.x - function vs iterator - issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, iterator, generator

I have inherited this chunk of code:

```
def _api_call(self, url, query=None, raw_query='', top=None, select=None, order_by=None, fetch_all=True,
              full_response=False, timeout=10, retries=3, debugging=False):
    if fetch_all and full_response:
        # these parameters are not compatible
        raise APIQueryException(message='fetch_all and full_response cannot be used together')
    query_string = self._encode_query(query, top, select, order_by)
    if query_string or raw_query:
        query_string = '?' + query_string + raw_query

    # get API signature headers for the new request from the api_auth singleton
    headers = api_auth.generate_headers(path=url, method='GET')
    service_end_point = 'https://%(portal)s.company.com%(url)s%(query_string)s' % {
        'portal': self._portal,
        'url': url,
        'query_string': query_string,
    }
    retries_left = retries + 1 or 1
    stop = False
    kwargs = {'headers': headers, 'timeout': timeout, 'fetch_all': fetch_all}
    accumulated_results = []

    while not stop:
        service_end_point, _tmp_res, stop = self._single_api_call(service_end_point, retries_left, stop, **kwargs)
        accumulated_results.extend(_tmp_res)
    return accumulated_results

def _single_api_call(self, service_end_point, retries_left, stop, debugging=True,**kwargs):
    _res = []
    headers = kwargs.pop('headers')
    timeout = kwargs.pop('timeout')
    fetch_all = kwargs.pop('fetch_all')
    try:
        while True:
            if debugging:
                print('Company Service API:', service_end_point)
            result = requests.get(url=service_end_point, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
                break
            except RequestException as e:
                if retries_left > 0:
                    if debugging:
                        print('Company Service API EXCEPTION, retrying:', str(e))
                    retries_left -= 1
                else:
                    raise

    except requests.Timeout as e:
        raise APITimeoutException(e, message='API request timeout')
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        raise APIRequestException(e, message='API request DNS error or connection refused')
    except requests.TooManyRedirects as e:
        raise APIRequestException(e, message='API request had too many redirects')
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        raise APIRequestException(e, message='API request returned HTTP error status code')

    if result.status_code == 400:
        # Company often reports "Bad Request" if the query
        # parameters are not acceptable
        raise APIQueryException(message='API request failed, Company rejected query terms')

    try:
        parsed_result = json.loads(result.content)
    except ValueError as e:
        # an unknown failure mode
        raise APIRequestException(
            message='API request failed; no JSON returned; server said {}'.format(result.content))

    if 'value' in parsed_result:
        _res.extend(parsed_result['value'])
    else:
        pass

    if '@odata.nextLink' in parsed_result and fetch_all:
        service_end_point = parsed_result['@odata.nextLink']
    else:
        # no more pages
        stop = True
    return service_end_point, _res, stop
```

this works fine

```
call_1 = api_obj._api_call(url, *args, **kwargs)
len(call_1)
3492
```

however I'm trying to refactor it in order to use a generator, but I'm messing something up. 
I made the following changes to the `while not stop` section of the `_api_call` method:

```
    while not stop:
        try:
            service_end_point, _tmp_res, stop = self._single_api_call(service_end_point, retries_left, stop, **kwargs)
            accumulated_results.extend(_tmp_res)
            if stop:
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                yield _tmp_res
        except StopIteration:
            return accumulated_results
```

I see that each single call is computed, but the result is:

```
call_2 = api_obj._api_call(url, *args, **kwargs)
len(call_2)
3
```

each of the three item is a list with 1000 items, so I have a total of 3000 items in separate list, and not 3492 as in the original implementation.

How can I change/rewrite this in order to achieve that?

Comment: Why is this tagged both python-3.x and python-2.7? You have 3.6 in the title. Does it need to work in 2.7?

Comment: Also, it would really help to turn this into a [mcve] instead of a huge pile of mostly-irrelevant code that nobody can run without access to even more code and data that we don't have access to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to do it both ways at once, both `yield`ing and `return`ing. That is *legal*, but it doesn't mean what you probably want it to mean.

Also, you don't need to raise a `StopIteration` just to handle it and turn it into a `return` which the generator protocol is just going to turn back into a `StopIteration`. Just `return` and knock out two of those steps (and two extra chances to get something wrong). Or, in this case, we can just fall off the end of the `while not stop:` loop, just like the original code, and leave off the `return` because we then fall off the end of the function.

Meanwhile, your old code was adding each `_tmp_res` onto the list with `extend`, not `append`, which has the effect of "flattening" the list—if `_tmp_res` is a list of 1000 items, `extend` adds 1000 items onto the end of the list. But `yield _tmp_res` will just yield that 1000-item sub-list. You probably want `yield from` here:

```
while not stop:
    service_end_point, _tmp_res, stop = self._single_api_call(service_end_point, retries_left, stop, **kwargs)
    yield from _tmp_res
```

If you don't understand what `yield from` means, it's roughly equivalent (in this case) to:

```
    for element in _tmp_res:
        yield element
```

In general, `yield from` is much more powerful, but we don't need any of that power here. It will still be more efficient (although probably not enough to make a difference), and of course it's shorter and simpler, and it makes more sense once you wrap your head around the idea. But if your code needs to work in Python 2.7, you don't have `yield from`, so you'll have to use the loop over `yield` instead.

Comment: tnx, this works :) but is missing the last chunk:
`call_2 = list(api_obj._api_call(url, *args, **kwargs))`
`len(call_2)`
`3000`

Comment: @Luke Ah, yeah. you don't need to `if stop: return`; just fall of the end of the `while stop:` loop, just like the original code, and it will return at the right time (after yielding the last `_tmp_res`). I've edited it.